# Read TXT file with Cython and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, cython, cythonize

I have a massive dataset (text file) that is nearly 4GB and would like to work with the dataset using a pandas dataframe. I can read in the file but it takes a couple of minutes to read in all of the data.

So, I would like to leverage the speed of C using the Cython library.

I am having trouble finding out how to read a text file into a pandas dataframe using Cython.

Any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: Couple of minutes for reading a 4GB file looks quite reasonable IMO.

Comment: The pandas reader is already compiled and relatively fast. I don't think writing your own is worth the effort.

Comment: Cython or Python doesn't matter here, as the process is most likely bounded by I/O. Switch to parallel reading like Spark and you'll see an improvement by the order of num_workers

Comment: Read what `read_csv` says about `engine`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#specifying-the-parser-engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read it once and store it back as other file formats with faster I/O (e.g. HDF, pickle). You'll most likely see a 10x-20x improvement.

There's a rough comparison on each file format I/O speed and disk space in the official documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#performance-considerations

Comment: Seems like a solid explanation. Thanks.